# Should I have the options menu in every fragment or simply just in the overarching tabs activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-menu, onactivityresult

I have some slight issues with my menu items for my fragments. I have an overarching activity that hosts the fragments. I'm unsure whether I should have my menu options code in every single fragment and not the activity or simply just the activity? What is better  practice and what works best? One of my menu items is also affected by OnActivityResult and therefore that menu item doesn't work unless that method is posted into every fragment as well. This just seems like a lot of duplicated code. I would simply put everything in the main activity but that seems like bad practice and surely the main activity should have minimal code and the fragments should hold their own separate code. I need to use the OnCreateView method in my fragments in order to refresh an image adapter because the ViewGroup needs to be accessed. I'm just wondering what people's opinions are and what is best for simplicity of my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is alright to put your menu item in the activity's menu list when it semantically belongs to the activity, such as logging in and out. You can just start up some other activity with `startActivityForResult` and change the status of the menu item according to the result of `onActivityResult`.

In addition, fragments can also have `onActivityResult` method, so if you can separate the logic of `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` into one of your fragments, it might be a good idea to do everything in that fragment.

Comment: What do you mean by change the status of the menu item?

Comment: Also is there any way to make the startActivityForResult from my main Activity find the onActivityResult in my Fragment?

Comment: Changing the status of the menu item is just an example about logging in and out.

Comment: The result for `startActivityForResult` from your `Activity` should be  handled in the `onActivityResult` in your `Activity`. If you really need to notify that to your `Fragment`s, you should create a listener interface and make your `Fragment`s implement it. That way you can call the method in it from your `Activity`.